# Implementation of ExternalContext.getRequestLocale()

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, implementation

While working with Locale in my JSF 2.0 application out of curiosity I have tried to read the implementation logic of the method `getRequestLocale()` of `ExternalContext`.

`javax.faces.context.ExternalContext` is an abstract class. I have found that

- `com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl`
- `javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper`
- `com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext$ServletContextAdapter`

extends this class.

Among them the implementation of this method of the class `ServletContextAdapter` returns null. So I guess it is not useful for me.

The implementation of this method in `ExternalContextImpl` is:

```
public Locale getRequestLocale(){
    return this.request.getLocale();
}
```

And in `ExternalContextWrapper` is:

```
public Locale getRequestLocale() {
    return getWrapped().getRequestLocale();
}
```

In the implementation by `ExternalContextWrapper` the `getWrapped()` returns an instance `ExternalContext`. I guess it is may be actually `ExternalContextImpl` object.

And in the implementation of this method in `ExternalContextImpl` `this.request` is actually `javax.servlet.ServletRequest`.

Now `ServletRequest` is an interface which is implemented by

- `javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper` and extended by
- `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`.

I didn't find this method in `HttpServletRequest` and in `ServletRequestWrapper` the implementation is same as that of `ExternalContextImpl`.

Now here I lost the track. I am unable to find in which class I can find the actual implementation. If someone knows please help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpServletRequest` extends `ServletRequest` which provides the `getLocale()` method.

See the javadocs here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale()

And the javadocs say:

> Returns the preferred Locale that the client will accept content in, based on the Accept-Language header. If the client request doesn't provide an Accept-Language header, this method returns the default locale for the server.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I have said in the question, inside `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` there is no such method's implementation. Infact its an interface with signature `public abstract interface HttpServletRequest extends ServletRequest`.

Comment: Sure. But what exactly is your question now? Do you want to see the implementation of ServletRequest.getLocale()? This method is implemented in the container you are using. So you will have to look there. However I think the most important thing about this method is mentioned in the javadocs. So it should be clear what it does.

Comment: Yes I wanted to see the `ServletRequest.getLocale()`. Now as you have said that this method is implemented by the container that I am using which is JBoss AS 7. Do you know from where I can get this implementation?

Comment: AS7 uses JBoss Web, which is a fork of Apache Tomcat. I think this should be the implementation: http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossweb/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java